# Python .json() moving first item to end?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Response data:

```js
{
  "total": 488,
  "rankings": [
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "class": 8,
      "spec": 1,
      "total": 48801.38671875,
      "duration": 270381,
      "startTime": 1428524959504,
      "fightID": 34,
      "reportID": "9BwMKrNz1VamGQkq",
      "guild": "ABC",
      "server": "ABC",
      "itemLevel": 700
    }
  ]
}
```

When running it through `.json()` in the code below I get the "total" at the end of the output, which I'm thinking is what breaks my code to iterate through it.
Python2 code:

```
def wow_rankings():
    response = requests.get("https://www.warcraftlogs.com:443/v1/rankings/encounter/1691?metric=dps&size=20&difficulty=5&region=1&class=8&spec=1&bracket=0&limit=3&page=1&api_key=abc")

    json_data = response.json()
    print json_data #shows the "total" item at the end of the output not front.
    for i in json_data:
        rank_totals = i['total']
        for x in i['rankings']:
            rank_name = x['name']
            rank_class = x['class']
            rank_spec = x['spec']
            rank_total = x['total']
            rank_duration = x['startTime']
            rank_fightID = x['fightID']
            rank_reportID = x['reportID']
            rank_guild = x['guild']
            rank_server = x['server']
            rank_ilevel = x['itemLevel']
            print rank_totals
            print rank_name, rank_class, rank_total, rank_fightID, rank_guild, rank_server, rank_ilevel
```

I get:

```
for x in i['rankings']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

JSON Output:

```
{u'rankings': [{u'guild': u'BIZZNO', u'name': u'Kecks', u'fightID': 34, u'itemLevel': 700, u'server': u'Ra
vencrest', u'class': 8, u'reportID': u'9BwMKrNz1VamGQkq', u'startTime': 1428524959504, u'duration': 270381
, u'total': 48801.38671875, u'spec': 1}, {u'guild': u'\u0424\u044c\u044e\u0436\u043d', u'name': u'\u0422\u
044d\u0439\u043a\u0430\u0445\u0445', u'fightID': 8, u'itemLevel': 700, u'server': u'\u0421\u0432\u0435\u04
36\u0435\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0414\u0443\u0448', u'class': 8, u'reportID': u'Lndmj1NzRVwv
tMTg', u'startTime': 1427907142553, u'duration': 280126, u'total': 47983.8828125, u'spec': 1}, {u'guild': 
u'Encore', u'name': u'Yazuki', u'fightID': 14, u'itemLevel': 699, u'server': u'Illidan', u'class': 8, u're
portID': u'z4MC2yjYfBgHNxw1', u'startTime': 1427854657905, u'duration': 266207, u'total': 47540.2109375, u
'spec': 1}], u'total': 488}
```

Should I not be using `.json()` on the requests data? Seems to be an easier way of iterating through the data and setting it to variables.

Comment: In both Python dictionaries and JSON objects, the keys are *not ordered*. Don't rely on there being any order.

Comment: So why are you looping here at all? You don't have a list, you have one dictionary.

Comment: There could be multiple ranking outputs so I would need to iterate over each group of them and get the values, that's why I'm looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the order of the keys in the output; both Python dictionaries and JSON objects are *unordered*, meaning that you cannot rely on the order of the keys in the data structure.

You are looping over the dictionary, so `i` is each of the keys. It'll be bound to `'total'` and `'rankings'`, not to dictionaries. Since strings are sequences you can only use integers to index them, hence your error message; `'total'['total']` makes little sense.

Don't loop over the outer object. Use:

```
rank_totals = json_data['total']
print rank_totals
for x in json_data['rankings']:
    rank_name = x['name']
    rank_class = x['class']
    rank_spec = x['spec']
    rank_total = x['total']
    rank_duration = x['startTime']
    rank_fightID = x['fightID']
    rank_reportID = x['reportID']
    rank_guild = x['guild']
    rank_server = x['server']
    rank_ilevel = x['itemLevel']
    print rank_name, rank_class, rank_total, rank_fightID, rank_guild, rank_server, rank_ilevel
```

Comment: I nearly fall into this trap too +1

Comment: That worked great, but I'm getting unicode errors afterward...UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128). I see that this is due to the item like 'name' possibly containing special characters. but I don't see how to do any conversion. I tried rank_name = x['name'].encode(utf-8) but that didn't work either.

Comment: @SudoGaron JSON strings are Unicode values, yes. There we any number of ways you can run into errors with Unicode values though. Is the error connected with printing, concatenation, writing to a file or something else entirely? Perhaps you need to ask a new question for the problems you now face.

Comment: Yes it is when I'm doing a print rank_name after setting the value from JSON from above. I'll make a new question as google seems to have failed me, or I it.